# Boostrap Grid not responsive

Tags: html, grid

[image]

The image I have posted shows the code I have written. Not actually because the code in 7000 lines long, but the divs are shown below.

When one box gets longer such as Monday, it moves up all the other divs with it, such as Saturday and Sunday. I want the grids to float up to the top.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    `<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
mondays
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
tuesdays    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
wedsdays
    </div>

ECT.
  </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: I cannot he sure without seeing the actual code, but I suspect that if your code is 7000 lines long you are missing a closing </div> somewhere, causing the DOM to render the columns incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

What Bootstrap version do you use?
You did the right thing by the
[grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).
Please try the grid with a number. It should be like `col-sm-3` or `col-sm-4`.

Comment: thanks for the fast response. I am using boostrap 4. I tried the changes you recommended but nothing changed. the spacing was adjusted but nothing moved.